# Expected value of a diagonal

Tags: mathematical-statistics, expected-value

If I have $E[A] = B$, where $E$ is the expected value, $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and $\text{diag}$ refers to the vector of coefficients on its diagonal.

In this case, what will be the value of $E[\text{diag}(A)]$ ?  Is it $\text{diag}(B)$ or no?

Any help will be very appreciated!!

Comment: What kinds of objects are $A$, $B$, and "diag"?  If $A$ and $B$ are square matrices and "diag" refers to the vector of coefficients on its diagonal, then under the usual understanding of "$E$" as the expectation coefficient-by-coefficient the answer is obvious, so do you perhaps have a different understanding of what $E$ means? Or maybe $A$ and $B$ aren't matrices at all?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A and B are square matrices, diag is the diagonal. So my answer is correct? Ediag A = diag B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below I use $A_{i,j}$ to refer to the $i,j$ element of any matrix $A$. Note that $[E(A)]_{i,j}=E[A_{i,j}]$ i.e. the $i,j$ element of the [expected value of a matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Expectation_of_matrices) is the expected value of the $i,j$ element (I expect this might be the part you didn't know).

Let $M=E(A)$ be a matrix, where $M$ and $B$ are two square matrices of the same size.

Now your question amounts to "If $M=B$, is $\text{diag}(M)=\text{diag}(B)\,$?", which in turn is identical to asking:

"If two matrices have their corresponding elements the same ($M_{ij}=B_{ij}$) at each position in the matrix, do they have the same elements on the diagonal?"

The answer is of course, yes -- if all of the elements correspond ($M_{ij}=B_{ij}$ over all $i$ and $j$), the diagonals must do.

Comment: You might want to clarify that last sentence a little. Does "all elements the same" mean $a_{i,j} = b_{i,j} = c$ for all $i,j, 1 \leq i,j\leq n$ for some real number $c$ or $a_{i,j}=b_{i,j}$ for $i,j, 1 \leq i,j\leq n$ without requiring that all the $n^2$ elements be equal to some $c$?

Comment: Thanks @Dilip . Hopefully less potential ambiguity now. I also added more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I didin't know that $[E(A)]_{i,j}=E[A_{i,j}]$